# Forwarding references: reference parameter origin

Tags: c++, templates, forwarding-reference

The whole premise about forwarding references (aka universal references) is, that this function:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&&) { }
```

can result in the template parameter either being `int&` or `int`, depending if you call it with `int a{}; f(a)` or `f(5)` as example. But this is already a step too far I think. Because when I have a function like

```
template<typename T>
auto g(T) -> void {}
```

Then it always resolves the template parameter to `int`, regardless of the way I call it. And that although a `auto h(int&) -> void {}` is perfectly legal.

So what what rules are in place that allow the template parameter of `f` to be a reference, but not that of `g`?

Comment: I assume you've read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference so, what's unclear? I'm not being sarcastic. I find a lot of text on the matter unclear myself, but in order to write a good answer it helps to know where you have struggles.

Comment: I'll read through that, but I think the question is pretty clear? Why does f's template parameter resolve to T& when called with an lvalue, but g's not?

Comment: @Basti Because it can not. `T`  is just a `typename`. It doesn't automatically include the `&`. For that, you need to type the `&` or the `&&` like `g(T&)`.

Comment: Well T _does_ become T& when using a T&& param - that's the point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a specific exception in the template argument deduction rules for the case that a function parameter has the form `T&&` (cv-unqualified) where `T` is a template parameter. This special case is as seen in the question known as a *forwarding reference*.

For forwarding references, if the function argument is an lvalue, then an lvalue reference is deduced for `T` where usually no reference type would be deduced.

You can see that this really is a special rule just for this case by trying to use e.g. `const T&&` instead of `T&&`, for which the special rule does not apply. It will deduce a non-reference type for `T` in any case, although the function call may then not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can read Effective modern C++ for the answer, first chapter, it says that ,we can think of a function template as looking like this:

```
    template<typename T>
    void f(paramType param);
```

`T` and `paramType` is often differnent, paramType often contains adornments like const or reference qualifiers like `const T&`

and he talked about this in three cases

1. paramType is a pointer or reference type
2. paramType is a universal reference
3. paramType is neither a pointer nor a reference

your first function is case2, since it needs to deduce the type, `&&` here is a universal reference, and your second function is case3, paramType is neither a pointer nor a reference

> During type deduction for a template parameter that is a universal
> reference, lvalues and rvalues of the same type are deduced to have
> slightly different types.

- lvalues of type T are deduced to be of type T&
- rvalues of type T are deduced to be type T

so `f(a)` you got `f(int& && param)`
then it comes to the rule of "reference collapsing"

- rvalue reference to rvalue reference become rvalue reference
- all other references to references collapse into an lvalue reference

so you got `f(int& param)`